# Why would you use industry standard ETL?

Tags: api, ssis, etl, informatica

I've just started work at a new company who have a datawarehouse that uses some bizzare proprietary ETL built in PHP.

I'm looking for arguments as to why its worth the investment to move to a standard system such as SSIS or infomatica or something. The primary reasons I have at the moment are:

1. A wider and more diverse community of developers available for contract work, replacements etc.
2. A large online knowledge base/support networks
3. Ongoing updates and support will be better

What are other good high level arguments to bring a little standardisation in :)

The only real disadvantage is that a lot of the data sources are web apis returning individual row-by-row records which are more easily looped through with PHP as opposed to standard ETL.

Comment: When you want to run a transport company, you buy trucks - you don't build them. Same here. Don't try to compete with Informatica, Oracle, IBM, Microsoft, AbInitio, Pentaho, Taleo. They are quite good and have spent a lot of time on it. Take advantage of their tools instead of trying to re-invent the wheel. Unless ETL is your business and you're going to focus on it entirely, of course. This would be in general - more specific reasons have been named by Samik below.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more:

- Simplifies development and deployment process.
- Easy to debug and incorporate changes. Would reduce maintenance and enhancement costs.
- Industry standard ETL tools perform better on large volume of data as they use various techniques like, grid computing, parallel processing, partitioning etc.
- Can support many types for data as source or target. Less impact if source or target systems are migrated to a different data store.
- Codes are re-usable. Same component of code can be used in multiple processes.